# How to sort a grouped product category by number of associates

Tags: magento-1.9, category, sorting, grouped-products, category-products

I have a category with about 2500 products and all of them are **grouped products with some associates**. In the category I have a lot of them with only one associated but I need to sort the category, showing first, those with more than one associated product.

*For example: I have three grouped products with: 5, 4 and 3 associated products respectively and I want to sort the category like this:*

*GroupedProduct1(5 associated)*

*GroupedProduct2(4 associated)*

*GroupedProduct3(3 associated)*

Anybody knows any reference or method to do that? Thanks very much for advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a few ways to do this. One way is this.

1. Create an attribute that holds an integer and doesn't show on the frontend. Name this "Number of Associated/Child Products".
2. Create an observer to hook onto the `catalog_product_save_before` event to save the number of child products for grouped products only.
3. Rewrite `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List::_getProductCollection` to add an `ORDER BY` clause using your custom attribute. `$collection->getSelect()->__toString()->order('e.my_attribute ASC')` (or `DESC`) is the syntax.

This will require you to go through all of your grouped products and save them without once to populate the custom attribute. This in effect acts as a global position value as opposed to the category product positions, which apply to specific categories. I've never tried this, but it should work.